# How to install OpenCV on Ångström Linux?

Tags: opencv, beagleboard

I want to install [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) 2.2 on a [Ångström Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution) enviroment. I tried to install, but I didn't succeed. What are the steps to install OpenCV on Ångström Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angstrom 2011.03 on a BeagleBoard-xM. This has OpenCV 2.2 in the package manager (see e.g. [[1](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/repo/?pkgname=libopencv-highgui-dev)]).

So I just did:

> opkg install libopencv-highgui-dev

However, this only was successful at the 3rd attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same issue...

I have a BeagleBoard-xM rev.C and I made an Ångström Linux base-image using openembedded. All works fine!
Now, I'm trying to cross-compile a simple OpenCV application for the target using Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) 64-bit and a cross-compile toolchain ([Sourcery CodeBench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentor_Graphics#Products) Lite 2011.09-70 for ARM GNU/Linux), but some error occurred.

I tried to cross-compile another application, like nano, and it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided very little information, but here is what I'm assuming:

- You're using a [BeagleBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard)
- Your beagleboard has enough "umph" to actually run OpenCV applications
- You have compilation working on your BeagleBoard.

I would recommend you follow [this](http://maxgalemin.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-build-qt-framework-472-and.html) walkthrough.

And then, if

- It fails to compile, check your toolchain, and try compiling [nano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) or some other small application.
- If it compiles, but your OpenCV based applications don't work, make sure you have updated Ångström Linux recently, and your toolchain is recent.

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful.

```
opkg update
opkg install opencv
opkg install opencv-apps
```

Comment: # To update 
opkg update 
# To install opencv
opkg install opencv 
opkg install opencv-apps