# Using OpenCV on BeagleBoard XM

Tags: opencv, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I'm trying to compile simple OpenCV code on the [BeagleBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard) XM, running [Ångström Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution).

I know my way in OpenCV, but only under Windows and [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio). I'm fairly with non-Microsoft OSes.

I think I've installed OpenCV on the BeagleBoard (`opkg install opencv`, right?), and I've transferred my code, which for now look like this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.h>
int main()
{
    cv::Mat img(100, 100, CV_8U);
    cv::imshow("Hello world", img);
    cv::waitkey();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I compile this code under the BeagleBoard? How can I tell it where the .so files are? Where are the OpenCV .so files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at *[ECE597 OpenCV on the BeagleBoard](http://elinux.org/ECE597_Opencv_on_the_BeagleBoard)* for installation instructions.

If you have installed it properly, then open a terminal window and browse to the folder where you have put the code. Once there, use the following command to compile the code in file "main.cpp"

```
g++ main.cpp -o out `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

After the code is compiled, use the following command to execute it.

```
./out
```

Also look at the answers to Stack Overflow question *[How to install OpenCV on Ångström Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682678)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -g -o NameOfProgram main.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Probably these commands should the work. Just don't forget to change the cpp filename if needed. See [this](http://it-it.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=135375324361).